# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis journal record explanation

Tags: activemq-artemis

And so, I have some missing messages from Apache Active MQ Artemis (for more information my previous question is located here [Apache ActiveMQ Artemis how to investigate if messages were lost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303170/apache-activemq-artemis-how-to-investigate-if-messages-were-lost)).

After reviewing journal records I see these entries related to the lost message (recordID=1094612593). What can I deduce from these entries. And can they be helpful in further troubleshooting?

```
operation@AddRecordTX;txID=1094612560,recordID=1094612593;userRecordType=45;isUpdate=false;compactCount=0;Message(messageID=1094612593;userMessageID=aa844c3f-1c6e-11ec-840c-005056be4b8b;msg=CoreMessage[messageID=1094612593,durable=true,userID=aa844c3f-1c6e-11ec-840c-005056be4b8b,priority=4, timestamp=Thu Sep 23 16:03:37 EEST 2021,expiration=0, durable=true, address=[===myQueue===],size=1277,properties=TypedProperties[===PROPERTIES==]]@1335046207

operation@UpdateTX;txID=1094612540,recordID=1094612663;userRecordType=32;isUpdate=true;compactCount=0;AddRef;QueueEncoding [queueID=7]
operation@UpdateTX;txID=1094612655,recordID=1094612663;userRecordType=33;isUpdate=true;compactCount=0;ACK;QueueEncoding [queueID=7]
operation@DeleteRecord;recordID=1094612663
```

P.s

I've tried to reproduce the loss situation, but to no avail.

Comment: Which message was actually lost? Was it `1094612593` or `1094612663`?

Comment: message 1094612663

Comment: According to the journal `1094612663` was acknowledged and removed (i.e. not "lost").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data here is inconclusive as the records don't directly relate to one another. Let's look at each record one by one...

```
operation@AddRecordTX;txID=1094612560,recordID=1094612593;userRecordType=45;isUpdate=false;compactCount=0;Message(messageID=1094612593;userMessageID=aa844c3f-1c6e-11ec-840c-005056be4b8b;msg=CoreMessage[messageID=1094612593,durable=true,userID=aa844c3f-1c6e-11ec-840c-005056be4b8b,priority=4, timestamp=Thu Sep 23 16:03:37 EEST 2021,expiration=0, durable=true, address=[===myQueue===],size=1277,properties=TypedProperties[===PROPERTIES==]]@1335046207
```

This is an "add message" record that contains the actual message data (i.e. the body and the properties & headers). The ID for this record (i.e. `1094612593`) will be reference by other records which relate to this message.

```
operation@UpdateTX;txID=1094612540,recordID=1094612663;userRecordType=32;isUpdate=true;compactCount=0;AddRef;QueueEncoding [queueID=7]
```

This is an "add ref" record. Since a single message can actually be on multiple queues (e.g. in several subscriptions on a JMS topic) the message data isn't  duplicated each time. Instead a "ref" is added to each queue (i.e. `queueID=7` in this case), and each "ref" points back to the ID of the actual message (i.e. `1094612663` here). In this case `1094612663` doesn't match the "add message" record ID of `1094612593` so these journal entries are related to 2 different messages.

```
operation@UpdateTX;txID=1094612655,recordID=1094612663;userRecordType=33;isUpdate=true;compactCount=0;ACK;QueueEncoding [queueID=7]
```

This is an "ack" record which indicates that a message was acknowledged. Messages can be acknowledged by a client (e.g. during normal consumption) or they can be acknowledged administratively (e.g. during a delete operation via the management API).

```
operation@DeleteRecord;recordID=1094612663
```

This is a "delete" record which is added to the journal once all the "refs" of a message have been acknowledged. The `recordID` refers back to the original "add message" record.

Later during a process called "compaction" all of the delete records will be cleaned up along with the records they reference including the ref and ack records. In this way usable space within the journal file can be freed and re-used.